# Using a BlazorWebView, how to call a C# method inside index.razor file

Tags: blazor, maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI project and I am fairly new to working with the BlazorWebView, I have the following view containing a BlazorWebCiew:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBlazorApp"
             x:Class="TestBlazorApp.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
    <StackLayout>
        <BlazorWebView x:Name="WebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       HeightRequest="800" WidthRequest="400">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Main}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
        <Button Text="Click Me!"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding DigitCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ICommand DigitCommand { set; get; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //WebView.

        DigitCommand = new Command<string> (
                execute: async (string arg) =>
                {
                });
 
    }
}
```

I have the following index.razor file Containing a couple of functions in C#

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<Xterm @ref="_terminal" Options="_options" AddonIds="_addonIds" OnFirstRender="@OnFirstRender" />

@code {
    private Xterm _terminal;

    private TerminalOptions _options = new TerminalOptions
    {
        CursorBlink = true,
        CursorStyle = CursorStyle.Bar,
    };

    private string[] _addonIds = new string[]
    {
        "xterm-addon-fit",
    };

    private async Task OnFirstRender()
    {
        // Invoke fit() function
        await _terminal.InvokeAddonFunctionVoidAsync("xterm-addon-fit", "fit");

        await _terminal.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

    private async Task OnKey(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        //await _terminalEvent.WriteLine($"({++_eventId}) OnKey(): Key: {args.Key}, Ctrl: {args.CtrlKey} {JsonSerializer.Serialize(args)}");

        await _terminal.Write(args.Code);
    }

    public async void TerminalWrite(String key)
    {
        await _terminal.Write("A");
    }
}
```

I need to call the function TerminalWrite(String key) inside the index.razor when the Button on the view is pressed. I need help figuring out how to do this..

Comment: Maybe [this call could help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/blazorwebview#access-scoped-services-from-native-ui).

Answer (score 1):

Having something similar (a WinForms .NET 8 C# application with a BlazorWebView) I actually came up with a solution that seems to work.

For the following lines I do have a "MainWindow" class that is a WinForms form that contains an "Index.razor" razor file.

First, I defined a helper class:

```csharp
public sealed class MainFormContext
{
    // This is the callback that will be called
    // from the native WinForms form instance.
    public EventCallback<string> OnSomethingHappend { get; set; }
}
```

Next, this is how the (simplified) constructor of my MainForm form looks like:

```csharp
public class MainForm : Form
{
    // This instance is used to connect the WinForms form instance
    // and the "Index" razor component instance.
    public MainFormContext Context { get; }

    public MainForm()
    {
        Context = new();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddWindowsFormsBlazorWebView();

        // Add my context instance by DI.
        services.AddSingleton(Context);

        /*
        // Or, alternatively, add as a cascading value,
        // both ways should work.
        services.AddCascadingValue(_ => Context);
        */

        blazorWebView.HostPage = @"wwwroot/index.html";
        blazorWebView.Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Add my Razor component.
        blazorWebView.RootComponents.Add<Index>(@"#app");
    }

    ...
}
```

The simplified "Index" Razor component looks like this:

```csharp
@* // The DI-injected Context from the WinForms "MainForm" form. *@
@inject MainFormContext Context

@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        // Use the injected context to tell the WinForms
        // "MainForm" instance about my callback handler.
        Context.OnSomethingHappend = 
            EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, OnSomethingHappend);

        // Please note that if you chose to add the "Context" as a 
        // cascading value instead of using DI, you have to change
        // the above code.
    }

    private async Task OnSomethingHappend(string folder)
    {
        // Do something with the passed information.
        ...

        // Optionally enforce UI refresh.
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
}
```

Then, in the WinForms "MainForm" form, add a click handler:

```csharp
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call the callback.
    await Context.OnSomethingHappend.InvokeAsync("test");
}
```

Please note that the button click handler can only succeed if the BlazorWebView is already initialized and the "Index" Razor component already subscribed to the "OnSomethingHappend" event.

I do hope this leads to no memory leaks or other unstable state but right now it seems to work pretty good in my tests. If there are better/cleaner ways to do this, please comment here.

---

#### Update 1

Out of curiosity, I tried the other way around, and it worked, too.

I.e. you can use the same approach of having another "EventCallback" in the "MainFormContext" class, bind it from the "MainForm" WinForms form and call it from the "Index" Razor component.

This enables you to call C# code in the WinForms code from the Blazor/Razor component.

---

#### Update 2

In some cases I do think the Blazor UI did get stuck in some kind of "weird" state and did not interact anymore.

I'm not quite sure why but it seems that this could happen when calling a Blazor method in WinForms from another thread than the UI thread.

What helped me was to decouple this through the [Application.Idle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.idle) event, at least when no direct method result has to be returned back to the WinForms code:

1. Subscribe to the Application.Idle event.
2. Have a "global" queue of action delegates.
3. Place the code that wants to call from WinForms to Blazor into the "global" queue.
4. Wait until the next time my Application.Idle event handler is called and process one item of the "global" action queue.

This, to my understanding ensures that the action delegate is always called from the main UI thread.

The disadvantage is that this is not as fast (in terms of time that passed until my action delegate is called) as a direct method call and that there is no way to return a result to the caller.

If you have to return a result to the caller you might want to do this in the Blazor C# code by calling a method in WinForms to pass the result back (and handle this also through the Application.Idle wrapper on the receiving WinForms code).